# Fatal Error when installing Sqlite Browsers V 1.1

Tags: sqlite, qt, browser, compiler-errors

I am trying to install version 1.1 of sqlite browser on Ubuntu 12.10, since every time I attempt to open a sqlite3 database, the program throws an error. Apparently the fix is to install version 1.1. Anyway, Im new to Linux, but I attempted to follow the installation instructions. I first ran qmake (which didnt return anything) and then ran make. I ran into the following error. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
gerard@gerard-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src/trunk/sqlitebrowser$ make
cd sqlitebrowser/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/trunk/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser'
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_QT3SUPPORT_LIB -DQT3_SUPPORT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support -I/usr/include/qt4 -Isqlite_source -I.moc -o .obj/extendedmainform.o extendedmainform.cpp
In file included from extendedmainform.h:4:0,
                 from extendedmainform.cpp:1:
form1.h:4:22: fatal error: qvariant.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [.obj/extendedmainform.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/trunk/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser'
make: *** [sub-sqlitebrowser-make_default] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix the sqlitedb.h:
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/forums/forum/301849/topic/4545126 see comment #2
2. Edit the Makefile:
   Add

> -ldl

at the end of the row beginning with LIBS =

paupla

Comment: Thanks! But actually I did not need the second step. It seems, only sqlitedb.h was broken.